# How Reindex and Reset programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, reindex, programmatically, external-script

I Need to reindex and reset the indexer programmatically using external script from magento root.

How can i achieve this.Is there a Way to do this.?

I am new in magento. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please go through this link. you can use this code for re-indexing externally.

https://github.com/estvivek/External_magento_2_reindex_reset/blob/master/reindex_core.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create one file on root directory.

```
<?php 

print_r(exec('php bin/magento indexer:reindex >> var/log/reindexing.log 2>&1 &'));

// If you want to only reindex 'customer_grid' then you can use below line
print_r(exec('php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid >> var/log/reindexing.log 2>&1 &'));

echo "Done";
```

You can see log in `var/log/reindexing.log`.

Hope this will help you!